# How to check a string for both up case and lowercase

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

The data in my grails app is intermixed with `ALL RED` `allred` or `ALLReD`

How would I compare this in my query:

```
def getColor (String color) {
 def reqCount = c.count {
   eq("color", color)
 }
}
```

Is there a way to do make data from DB all caps and make the `color` value all caps and then compare the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DetachedCriteria or where query?

```
Color.where { color =~ "$color" }.count()
```

or

```
Color.countByColorIlike(color)
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could add Ilike to the dynamic count.

Comment: Agree, these are minute features which easily slips out of mind. Happens to me as well. :) @JoshuaMoore

Answer (score 1):

Use the case insensitive matching of `ilike`:

```
def getColor (String color) {
 def reqCount = c.count {
   ilike("color", color)
 }
}
```

Check the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) on criteria for more information.

Comment: hmm how would I do this for `Color.countByColor(color)`

Comment: Apparently you can use Color.countByColorIlike(color) as indicated in another answer.